# "Undefined index: path" on wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a Wordpress post using PHP, and something's going wrong and I can't figure it out.  My background is not PHP, and no traceback is being delivered to me--just this error by itself:

```
Error: Undefined index: path
```

Here is my post creation code:

```
function generate_query_args($campaign_id, $user_id) {
    $query_args = array(
        'post_parent' => $campaign_id,
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish', /*array('publish'),*/
        'paged' => '',
        'log_type' => 'sale',
        'post_title' => 'Autogenerated by Heroku setup',
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_excerpt' => '',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'edd_log_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'sale'
            )
        )
    );
    return $query_args;
}

$post_id = wp_insert_post(generate_query_args($campaign_id, $user_id));
```

As far as I can tell from the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), I'm doing everything I'm supposed to be.

**Update:**

This is the entirety of what I run and see in return:

```
>> $post_id = wp_insert_post($query_args, true);
Error: Undefined index: path
```

I'm using [Wordpress console](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-console/).

**More information:**

WordPress 3.9.1 running Fundify Child Theme theme.

Plugins (there are a lot of them, not my WP site):

Admin Bar Disabler, Akismet, Astoundify by Crowdfunding Custom Fields, BAW Login/Logout Menu, Coming Soon, CRED Frontend Editor, Crowdfunding by Astoundify, Dropifi Contact Widget, Easy Digital Downloads, Easy Digital Downloads - Record Test Payments, Easy Digital Downloads - Stripe Payment Gateway, Google Analytics for WordPress, Gravity Forms, Gravity Forms + (More) Stripe, Gravity Forms + Stripe Connect, Gravity Forms MailChimp Add-On, Module Manager, Nav Menu Roles, Peter's Login Redirect, Restrict Content Pro, Restrict Content Pro - Math Verification, Restrict Content Pro - Stripe, Revolution Slider, Seed Prod Coming Soon pro, Simple Tooltips, Soundcloud Shortcode, TinyMCE Advanced, Types, Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer, User meta shortcodes, Wordpress Console, Wordpress SEO, WPBakery Visual Composer, WP Views

**Post-mortem:**
Ultimately, this may have been an error with the Console plugin, since when I simply ran the code as part of Wordpress, it ended up working.

Comment: What line does it say the error is on? Not coming from the code you posted...

Comment: It doesn't.  It provides me with absolutely no traceback at all.

Comment: Can you add the version of WordPress you're using, including any plugins that may be activated?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the error is not produced by your posted code . In all likelihood , It is produced by one of the numerous other plugins on your site . The error just means, usually, that a variable ( `path` in this case  )was not properly defined or initialized ( has no value ) and later is not properly checked for validity. I suggest that you will test your code first on a *CLEAN* wp install, and only then try and test on the real environment. Developing with tens of other plugins can be close to impossible to debug.. Just imagine how many error can one poor plugin have, now think x40

Comment: surely a error with console itself? put it like this, if you run the code in your functions file it works perfectly?

Comment: Why are you passing query args to wp_insert_post?

Comment: @henrywright the variable is called `$query_args` just because of where I copied it from.

Comment: I actually meant your use of `tax_query`.

Comment: @henrywright, ah, well that would be me not knowing WordPress at all and just copying what I saw.  I will remove that if it shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think that is actually your problem. See my answer below for what can be included in the $post_data array.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, I'd tried before without `tax_query` and tried again just now, and I still get the same error.  Even completely redid the args to match your `wp_insert_post` `$post_data`; same issue.

Comment: @jdotjdot - please read my comment above again.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, I did see your comment--if it comes down to that I will try that, though I'm hoping not to have to.

Comment: @jdotjdot - then just search all your plugins for a variable named `$path` and you will find the culprit - But again, it is much more easy to just verify first that your own code is right . I have been developing wp plugins for years - and depending on other people´s mistakes is a no-no.. But have it your way .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I actually was able to solve it without using a fresh WP install.  I did a full code search on `['path']` and `$path` and `->path` and never found it, but I made some other changes that ended up making the issue go away.

Comment: @jdotjdot - Can you elaborate on those changes in order to help others that might have similar problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_insert_post()` should be used like this:

```
$post_data = array(
    'post_status'           => 'draft', 
    'post_type'             => 'post',
    'post_author'           => $user_ID,
    'ping_status'           => get_option('default_ping_status'), 
    'post_parent'           => 0,
    'menu_order'            => 0,
    'to_ping'               => '',
    'pinged'                => '',
    'post_password'         => '',
    'guid'                  => '',
    'post_content_filtered' => '',
    'post_excerpt'          => '',
    'import_id'             => 0
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

For a full list of what you can include in the `$post_data` array see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post